# Converting PyTorch Module to Networkx Graph?

Tags: pytorch, networkx

What's the simplest way to convert a PyTorch module (e.g. an RNN, LSTM) into a Python networkx graph?

Comment: Did you know PyThorch geometric? ( https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ) or are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: PyTorch geometric appears to be all about modules performing graph operations. I want to transform weight matrices of a module into a graph. Is there a connection between these two goals?